# Deserialize and sort

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json format file, rankingOutput

```
{
    "12345": {
        "ABC": {
            "rank": 3, 
            "Comments": [
                "Good"
            ]
        }, 
        "DEF": {
            "rank": 2, 
            "Comments": [
                "Good"
            ]
        }, 
        "GHI": {
            "rank": 1, 
            "Comments": [
                "Bad"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I ma having the following deserialize code

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RankingsClass>>>(
                                               System.IO.File.ReadAllText(rankingOutput));

    public class RankingsClass
    {
        public int rank;
        public string[] comments;
    }
```

Though the above code deserializes it properly, I am wondering if there is an option so that my deserializer will return the strings "ABC", "DEF" and "GHI" ranked in ascending order according to the rank field.

Comment: Dictionaries have no ordering whatsoever. You can use a SortedDictionary instead.

Comment: Where should the soretdDictionary be? something like this? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, RankingsClass>>>(
                                               System.IO.File.ReadAllText(rankingOutput))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Linq on the result set like:

```
List<RankingsClass> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RankingsClass>>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(rankingOutput));

return list.OrderByDescending(c => c.rank);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` is an unordered collection.  There is no way for you to have any expectation of any order at all for the items in it.  You'll need to use an entirely different data structure that is actually ordered, such as a `SortedDictionary`.